# Update an item in an object nested in an array with feathersJs and Reactjs

Tags: mongoose, feathersjs

I am using feathersjs for my backend and my users service/collection resembles such:

```
{ name :'my Name',

email: 'example@gmail.com',

_id "9878787977377827..."
students:[
{name: 'student 1 name', _id: 2113232..., active: true},
{name: 'student 2 name', _id: 2113232..., active: true}
]
}
```

... I will like to change for example the active status of student one to false.
I tried this

```
client.service('users').update({ 'students._id': id },
{$set: {'students.$.active': false,}},function (err, model) {if (err) {console.log(err);}})
```

but nothing seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

If you are here, I was able to patch sub docs (students) by using this query,

```
const query = { "subdoc._id": id }
  client.service('users').patch(mainDoc._id, { "students.$.active": false 
  }, { query });
```

in my case;

```
const query = { "students._id": id }
client.service('users').patch(user._id, { "students.$.active": false 
}, { query });
```

To patch a single particular object in my array of students, i pass in the id of the main document which is the user._id and the _Id of the nested object  which the _id of the student, then I set student.active to false. Thanks.

follow this link if still confused. 
    https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose/issues/208